# Elements disappear in certain scroll positions in Firefox

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox, desktop

I've encountered a strange bug which I'm not able to solve for some time.

The bug appears in Firefox when scrolling in certain resolution (Macbook pro 2019 15", 1680x1050) - product elements (not only images) start to flicker.

I've made a video of the bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xByt25fbaYs

Now this is where it gets weeeird:

1. If i open dev tools - the flickering stops. If dev tools are closed, the flickering stops. Until pages is reloaded
2. If I change resolution settings or just resize the browser, flickering also stops.

Link to the problem: http://vilmers.vsbl-dev.lt/sofas/

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I don't know why but while debugging I've set elements which were disappearing background colour and it fixed the issue for some reason.